# Core Data error: "Cannot find item in scope", Persistence

Tags: swift, core-data

When archiving a project I get error "Cannot find View in scope" under Persistence. The error only lasts for a second before it's gone, and then the archiving fails.

This is where I get the error:

```swift
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
        }
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
    }()
}
```

The error is supposedly on this line, but as I said, only for a few seconds:

```
let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
```

BTW, it compiles and runs fine on iPhone and simulator.

I have been googling for a long time now, so I hope someone can help.

I commented out the `for` loop and now it seems to work. Why did this happen? I have never done anything in this file ever before.

Comment: A static property inside a singleton makes no sense. Remove `static` before `var preview`, it's supposed to be an instance property.